# Unable to set Prompt Box value using Selenium Chrome driver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium Chrome driver to automate a web application in Chrome browser. I get a Prompt Box pop-up where I am unable to enter a value.
Here is the code-

```
chromeDriver.SwitchTo().Alert().SendKeys("Some value");
```

The code executes successfully but there is no value set in the textbox, inside the Prompt Box.
Although I am able to get the text value of the Prompt  box using this code-

```
chromeDriver.SwitchTo().Alert().Text;
```

My Chrome version is- 46.0.2490.80

Any idea why it is not working?

Comment: Could you share Prompt Box pop-up code as well??

Comment: Sadly I do not have access to the web app code for the Prompt-Box. It is a third party app that I am trying to automate. But it is just like a usual Prompt Box with a textbox for an input, and OK and Cancel butttons.

Comment: By Prompt Box are we talking a JS Prompt box or something done with HTML? It looks like a JS box since .Alert() is working but I wanted to confirm (and you might want to specify that in your question just for extra clarity).

Comment: @JeffC It's a JS prompt. I copies the HTML text which triggers it- <a name="$ICField14$hfind$0" id="$ICField14$hfind$0" tabindex="16" onclick="return FindString_main0(document.main0.ICFind);" href="javascript:submitAction_main0(document.main0,'$ICField14$hfind$0');" class="PSLEVEL1SCROLLAREAHEADER">Find</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try
   {
      IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
   if (alert != null)
   {
      alert.SendKeys("Some value");
      alert.Accept();
   }
}
catch (Exception ex) { }
```

Comment: This works! Meanwhile, I just discovered that my previous code works too in the same way. Only thing is that, we don't see any values being passed in the Prompt Box. May be it is getting passed internally? I was just struggling to see why there is no value getting entered in the input box inside the Prompt. The issue is resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
chromeDriver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys("Some value");
```

Comment: It gives below exception-   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.InternalExecute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteTargetLocator.ActiveElement()